# undefined value in a component method

Tags: reactjs

This is what I have:

```
class StorePicker extends React.Component {
    myInput = React.createRef();

    goToStore = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const storeName = this.myInput.value.value;
        console.log(storeName);
        this.props.history.push(`/store/${storeName}`);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className= 'store-selector' onSubmit={this.goToStore}>
                <h2>Please Enter A Store</h2>
                <input type= 'text'
                       ref={this.myInput}
                       required placeholder='Store Name'
                       defaultValue={getFunName()}/>
                <button type= 'submit'>Visit Store</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
export default StorePicker;
```

But on submit button I get an error that "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be accessing the wrong property: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs . It should be `this.myInput.current.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refs created using `createRef` or `useRef` react hook are accessed as such `ref.current`, to get the value stored in them.

[Accessing Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs)

```
const storeName = this.myInput.current.value;
```

Comment: oh interesting.  So it has changed. I was following an online course and he was using .value.value ... no wonder my own IDE was suggesting .Current too.

Comment: The older way setting and using refs sort of did that, [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), but refs created with `createRef` or `useRef` hook access the value stored in the `current` property.